# How to place div so that it sizes with parent window?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a website together and have a "content" area on all the pages so that i can have a template for all the other pages.  I have it set up except that the new divs i place dont resize properly to the main window, it looks good until i minimize the window then the div (menu and action divs)  then they dont resize with it.  I am trying to figure out the menu and action divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Centered Scalable Layout using &lt;div&gt;'s</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999999;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FBFBFF;
    color: #000033;
}
#header {
    height: 6em;
    background: #000059;
    color: #F2F2FF;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:900px;
    position:relative;
}
#action{
    position:absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
#menu{
    position:absolute;
    left: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 500px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #80A7E0;
    color: #000033;
}

</style>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"> Header area</div>
  <div id="content"> 
    <p>Some text in the content area.  </p>

    <div id="menu"> menu area</div>
    <div id="action">action area</div>
  </div>
  <!--end content div -->

  <div id="footer">Footer area</div>
</div><!--end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What do you want the @menu and #action div's to do?

Comment: I think you need to incorporate a screen shot of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to interpret what you are wanting exactly.

From what I understand, you are wanting a flexible design that elements will resize depending on the browser window?

**Take a look at this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q62AM/1/**

**Thanks to @Jared Farrish for putting together the jsfiddle for everyone to play with.*

Basically, with flexible designs you need to use flexible increments such as percentages. You can set `min-width`s if you don't wish for your design to squash too small but you should consider setting the `min-width` on the parent container.

Check out the following excellent articles for further information on building responsive and fluid layouts:

**A List Apart - Fluid Grids:** http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

**Smashing Magazine - Responsive Web Desing:** http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/